# Use previous store , compare name with collection and use in next step

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I am fairly new to gremlin. For a project I am working with Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG).
Here is a subgraph (with names changed).
[image]

There are levels (from 0 to 3 in this graph).
I need to traverse from Level0. Id:0 to Level3, Id:7. (shown in green here).
Id's are irrelevant. Edges are irrelevant. "Name" property is important and forms a hierarchy.
Here Level3 nodes have same name as level1 except for added suffix.
I am working with AWS Jupyter Notebook

So far I've following gremlin query.

```
%%gremlin
g.V().has('Level0', 'name', 'node0').out()
.as("level1").sideEffect(__.values('name').store('level1_list'))
.out().as("level2").store('level2_list')
// need to compare with 'level1_list' here
.out().and(__.has('name', TextP.startingWith( 'node' ))).store('level3-list') 
.dedup()
.path()

level1_list = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3']
level3_list = ['node1-suffix2', 'node2-suffix2', 'node3-suffix2']
```

Desired =  `level3_list = ['node3-suffix2']`

The query works when I just compare single string at `TextP.startingWith`. But I need to check if current node  under traversal at Level3  starts with any node in `level1_list`
I am not able to get that to work.
something like.

.out().and(__.has('name', in('level1_list')).store('level3-list')
but other way around.

Also, based on my research I cant split strings easily within gremlin. Else I could have tried to match partial strings for name at level3 with partial string within `level1_list`
something like.

```
(__.has(<partial node name split on '-'>  in('level1_list'))
```

so I guess key question is how do I compare a node name with another list acquired within the query.
In python I could have done following easily,

```
>>> level1_list = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3']
>>> [ item for item in level1_list if item in 'node1-suffix2']
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1)**
I've updated graph to reflect correct desired traversal path.

As per suggestion, I have made label / name identical and also added respective 'name' from vertex at level1  as property to respective vertex in level3.

For e.g.
After traversing levle1, i'll have a collection

```
.as("level1").sideEffect(__.values('name').store('level1_list'))

level1_list = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3']
```

Now, after adding 'name' of respective vertex from level1 to property in vertices at level3, I'll have following example schema. for vertex : `node1-suffix1`

```
{
 "id" : "node1-suffix1"
 "name" : "node1-suffix1"
 "attributes" : {
     "level1_node" : "node1",
     ..............
  },
 "from" : ... // not imp here
 "to" : ... // not imp here
}
```

So the question is how do I traverse level3 while only filtering respective vertex (here node1-suffix2)

something like

```
.out()
.and(__.has('attributes.level1_node', within('level1_list')))
.as('level3-list')
. < level4 traversal>
. < next level traversal>
```

Essentially checking if `attributes.level1_node` for each vertex at this level is within collection `level1_list`
The query should filter only node1-suffix2 vertex.

```
level3-list = [ v[node1-suffix2 ]]
```

**Edit2)**

*GraphBuilding Steps:*

```
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import P
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Cardinality
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import valueMap
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import local
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import path
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal

g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))
single = Cardinality.single
id = T.id


g.addV('level0').property(id,0).property(single, 'name', 'node0').next()
g.addV('level1').property(id,1).property(single, 'name', 'node1').next()
g.addV('level1').property(id,2).property(single, 'name', 'node2').next()
g.addV('level1').property(id,3).property(single, 'name', 'node3').next()
 g.addV('level2').property(id,4).property(single, 'name', 'node4').next()
g.addV('level3').property(id,5).property(single, 'name', 'node1-suffix1').property(single, 'attributes', {'level1_node' : 'node1'}).next()
g.addV('level3').property(id,6).property(single, 'name', 'node2-suffix2').property(single, 'attributes', {'level1_node' : 'node2'}).next()
g.addV('level3').property(id,7).property(single, 'name', 'node3-suffix1').property(single, 'attributes', {'level1_node' : 'node3'}).next()
g.addV('level3').property(id,8).property(single, 'name', 'node4-suffix1').property(single, 'attributes', {'level1_node' : 'node4’}).next()
g.addV('level3').property(id,9).property(single, 'name', 'node5-suffix2’).property(single, 'attributes', {'level1_node' : 'node5}).next()


g.V().has('name', 'node0').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node1').as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
g.V().has('name', 'node0').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node2’).as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
g.V().has('name', 'node0').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node3’).as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()

g.V().has('name', 'node1').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node4').as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
g.V().has('name', 'node2').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node4').as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
g.V().has('name', 'node3').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node4').as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()

g.V().has('name', 'node4').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node1-suffix1').as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
g.V().has('name', 'node4').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node2-suffix2').as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
g.V().has('name', 'node4').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node3-suffix1').as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
g.V().has('name', 'node4').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node4-suffix1').as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
g.V().has('name', 'node4').as_('source').V().has('name', 'node5-suffix2’).as_('target').addE('links').from_('source').to('target').next()
```

Sample query returns empty collection `[]`.

```
g.V().has('level0', 'name', 'node0').as_('level0_list').store('level0_list')\
.out().as_('level1').store('level1_list').by('name')\
.out().as_('level2').dedup().store('level2_list')\
.out().as_('level3').values('level1_node')\
.where(P.within('level1_list')).store("level3_list").cap('level3_list').next()
```

So basically on last line of above query I need to go through every node and check if value of property 'level1_node' is in stored collection 'level1_list'. If yes, then store in 'level3_list' and proceed to next stage of traversal.

As you can see from graph, level3 has additional nodes that are not part of level1 nodes. To filter it we have property 'level1_node' thats same as corresponding level1 node.

So desired result for collection "level3_list" will be.

```
[ v[node1-suffix2 ],v[node2-suffix2 ],v[node3-suffix2 ]]
```

Comment: sorry, don't have graph handy with above data. I'll cook something up. But I am looking for partial string matches between a string (collected at level-3)and collection of string (collected at level-1)

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with a working query for this, but I suspect it's going to be quite tricky mixing `within` and `startingWith` and a collection of values.

Comment: In general I think I would consider a data model change here. Looking for matches using partial string compares is not going to be efficient. Doing exact matches using a property value, a label, or an ID is going to be more performant and make the queries a lot easier to write. So, for example, rather than look for strings that start with node, why not just make 'node' the label or a property valule?

Comment: that was a great suggestion. I don't have control over all levels of metadata. But I was able to make label / vertex 'name' property same and also add  'name'  of level-1 as a property of respective node in level-3. Now we just need to figure out how to parse it. Pls check updates in question.

Comment: One more small note, the `store` step is itself a side effect, so instead of doing `sideEffect(__.values('name').store('level1_list'))` you can just do `store('level1_list').by('name)`. If you can add the sample graph building steps that will definitely help with providing a tested answer. My sense is that the data model can still be further simplified. The key is to get to the point where you are able to do exact matches, along the lines of something being `within(some-collection)`

Comment: Hi @KelvinLawrence I added sample graph building steps and query and deleted other question. Apologies for confusion.